# What plasma temperature range to expect from Earth atmosphere common elements?

Tags: physics, chemistry, temperature

I intend to write a character that has the ability to turn nearby gasses into plasma for combat and utility purposes. However, I've been studying how plasma works and (as someone who is not as savvy with chemistry and physics as I would like) I've been struggling with understanding the energy and temperatures involved.

So while I'm still trying to wrap my head around all that stuff, I thought I would ask; **if someone was limited to only making plasma from available gasses around them (assuming surface level modern-day Earth atmosphere) what kind of temperatures would I be working with?** I'm mostly concerned with the most abundant gasses, presuming that not much can be done with gasses too minute in quantity in normal air.

From this, could this character make "cold" plasma that wouldn't burn someone? What about plasma that has enough energy to cause damage but not outright kill? Would they need to carry around gas tanks to be more flexible with what they can do if what's in the air is insufficient for something those last two things?

As I said, I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to physics and chemistry (at least, in these topics) so I'd appreciate any help on this, as trying to find these answers on my own has been tricky.

Comment: How about instead you say what you want, and ask how you might get it? Plasma is enormously variable stuff, especially with regards to the temperatures it can exist at (and exactly what "temperature" might mean).

Comment: I am interested more in exploring what can be done off of a premise and working with its limitations. So I am asking for what I am because I understand how variable the properties of plasma is, and would rather know what I can do, not how to do something specifically.

Comment: What is to be understood by the temperature of plasma is a very interesting question in its own right...

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows Is my question really too broad? Maybe I overcomplicated it, but the main question "what temperature range can I expect from plasmas created from gasses common in Earth's atmosphere" doesn't seem that open-ended to me.

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows That's the question in the title and the first question in the paragraph; I kind of assumed that people would realize that is the most important question, and that the other three questions after that would be useful additional points of information based on the answer of that first one.

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows Due to your suggestion I touched it up a bit. Hopefully, that makes things more clear to onlookers.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. +1

Answer (score 4):

When I was working towards a Ph.D. degree in Electrical Engineering, I studied and built plasma sources.

The term cold plasma is a shorthand term to signify as non-equilibrium plasma, which itself is a wonky term.  Plasmas can be in equilibrium or not.

When a plasma is said to be in equilibrium then all charge carriers (electrons and ions) are within the same temperature regime.

In a non-equilibrium plasma, the charge carriers are not of similar temperatures

In the image shown below, in the dark discharge region and the very beginning of the glow discharge region, the electrons can run at 1 eV which translates to 11,000 K -- or the surface temperature of the sun, but the ions can be room temperature.  Since the ions carry all the mass, effectively, these kinds of plasma don't transfer thermal energy.  This is the kind of plasma source is built into smoke detectors (they operate in the dark discharge region).  Similarly, there are atmospheric pressure plasma sources used for sterilizing and biological manipulation that operate in this non-equilibrium fashion.

Plasma sources generating equilibrium plasmas raise the temperature of both electrons and ions.  These are the kind used for applications ranging from industrial welding systems to Tokamak reactors.  And its the regime of stellar systems, too.

[image]

I never completed my Ph.D. but had fun gadgeteering non-equilibrium atmospheric plasma sources that projected needle-sized purple plumes of argon based plasmas between 1/4" and 5" long.  The more power the longer the plume.  1" plumes you could put your finger in and it tickled.  5" plumes would cause pieces of paper to brown and crinkle.  Never could get the gas from my Bic lighter to light though in the plume.

Comment: Excellent answer, found this [6minute u-tube vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnSRbnvm798) with nice pictures of a guy with a match-head/his finger taking advantage of a helium version. +1

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is the wrong way to think about something like this. Plasma is [hot](https://www.quora.com/At-which-temperature-does-gas-change-into-plasma). Really hot, as in a minimum of a few thousand Kelvins, to the point to tens of thousands of Kelvins. To put that in Fahrenheit terms, that's over 10,000 degrees Fahrenheit. There's no way to get this 'cold' or anything of that nature. Even using tanks of specialized elements won't help you, again, because plasma is *hot*.

Think about this in term of time and application. As xkcd points out, the proper morale of the story of Icarus isn't 'don't fly too close to the sun'. It's ['don't spend too much time there'](https://what-if.xkcd.com/115/). Have a plasma character use it sparingly, and in small batches to cause serious burns, or form a makeshift razor-thin plasma arc to slice through arms.

Comment: Maybe I have made a grievous error in my research, but I was under the impression that plasmas can be generated at varying temperatures based on how ionized it is. I get that "cold" isn't a good word to use since that's a very relative term (kind of why I put it in quotation marks), but unless I'm finding drastically false information, plasmas can exist in a form that won't immediately damage and burn someone.

Comment: @Necrikus Kind of? Plasma can be generated at different temperatures depending on how electrically charged it is, which is why you will generally see the energy represented in volts, or something of that nature. But it still requires a threshold to become plasma.

Comment: And even if that wasn't the case, than the electricity necessary would fry anyone it touches. I'm not calling it ball lightning because I don't have the knowledge to do it but basically that.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean then? If you agree that plasma can be generated at different temperatures, then what is wrong with my way of thinking? What do you mean by how it "requires a threshold to become plasma" and how does that tie into the argument?

Comment: In addition, I'm already starting this on the premise that an individual can create plasma. Not much point in questioning if they can survive doing so since we can presume I can wave that concern.

Comment: @Necrikus Whenever a substance changes states of matter from one form to the other, i.e. solid to liquid, it takes a certain minimum amount of energy (thermal energy). While plasma can be generated at a range of temperatures by cutting the needed thermal cost using electrical energy, the lowest temperature it can be created at is still way too high. If you're asking 'why can't I just keep increasing the electric energy until it turns to plasma', the answer is that the electric energy in this case will generate thermal energy upon becoming plasmafied. I'll be in the chat to talk further.

Comment: Whilst "cold" isn't the right term, "non-thermal" plasmas _do_ exist (where most of the energy is in the electrons, for example) and these can behave in certain ways as if they were cold. For example, you can use a "cold" plasma discharge to [safely sterilise the surface of your hands](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/02/14/business/14novel.html?_r=1&ref=technology), because the plasma discharge will fry bacteria but won't roast your hands any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

> could this character make "cold" plasma that wouldn't burn someone?

More or less, yes. As EDL pointed out, there are such things as non-equilibrium plasmas (which I've heard being called "non-thermal" plasmas, where the "thermal" bit specifically refers to [thermalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermalisation), not "non-hot"). Cold plasmas are in fact used commercially for things like [food processing and medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonthermal_plasma#Applications), because it is possible to zap microbes without zapping the food or people they may be attached to. Here's an example [hand sanitiser](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/02/14/business/14novel.html?_r=1&ref=technology).

[image: plasma hand sanitiser]

> What about plasma that has enough energy to cause damage but not outright kill?

Of course! Just, y'know, zap a small area. Killing people is quite difficult; they're the end product of a few billion years of work towards *not dying*. Making a plasma discharge that could kill someone, now that's a harder trick.

> Would they need to carry around gas tanks to be more flexible with what they can do if what's in the air is insufficient for something those last two things?

Well, the real problem you have here is that you want "plasma weapons", and that's a pretty ill-defined term. You've presumably got something in mind for your theme, but you haven't actually shared that with us which makes this whole thing a bit problematic.

Is a particle beam a plasma weapon? In which case you don't need a whole lot of fuel, but you need *quite a lot* of energy to accelerate your particles to a high enough speed to punch through the atmosphere. An electron beam needs a very specialist power source. Your dude isn't a plasma-user, so much as a pulsed-power source who can produce hazardous electrical discharges.

Are you thinking of throwing plasmoids around, hadouken-style? You'll have to shoot them out at a non-trivial fraction of the speed of light for them to hit their target before they expand and dissipate into harmlessness. Again, massive power required, not much fuel and not really very much plasma involved

Are you thinking of just spontaneously ionising a load of gas in the vicinity? Well, that's a bit like just starting fires. Interestingly coloured, very *hot* fires (at least initially) but the end result is basically "stuff bursts into flame near your dude".

Generating plasma on your hands and just *punching* someone with it, like you're in a comic book? You'd be better off just using your terrifying electrical discharge powers to shock them to death instead, and avoid all the silly wasteful ionisation of random objects.

So, yeah. Plasma attack? I don't know. Lightning bolts and pyrokinesis? Seems more likely. Is that what you want, though?